# C# How to control what DateTime Format does MySql Connector Returns as

Tags: c#, mysql, date, datetime

I am developing a C# application which connects to MySql. It returns some of MySql DateTime Fields.

When I call the following,

```
var Test = DR["ShiftReportDate"].ToString();
```

The results returned is in the format of "28/02/2017 7:00:00 PM" (dd/MM/YYYY).

To convert it to C# DateTime, I use

```
var ShiftReportDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DR["ShiftReportDate"]);
```

My Concern is what if the user of my software has a Date format of MM/dd/YYYY?
What will MySqlConnector return as? if it returns as "2/28/2017 19:00:00" all my Convert.ToDateTime will fail.

Answer (score 1):

The `ToDateTime` will use the culture of the user if you do not specify a culture (the way you have it in your question).

If you want, you can give the `ToDateTime` method a 2nd parameter to instruct it on what format to use like this:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var shiftReportDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DR["ShiftReportDate"], culture);
```

This will, obviously, use the `en-US` culture.

Answer (score 1):

Check the type of **DR["ShiftReportDate"]**.
Perhaps by stepping thru the code & evaluating **DR["ShiftReportDate"].GetType()**
If the MySql provider returns a value of type DateTime, this is in a culture-neutral binary format.
Do not get confused by calling ToString() on an object - for DateTime objects ToString() will use local system settings to format the string for output.
This does not change the fact that the underlying object, be it a DateTime or floating point number or anything else, is stored in a binary format that is independent of formatting preferences.
Of course if the type you're getting from the provider is just a formatted string, you should coerce the value into a culture-neutral string like ISO 8601 in your SQL query, so converting in C# is failsafe.